# NuGet: What's the appropriate "FrameworkName" for creating packages with Windows Phone 7 binaries?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, windows-phone-7, nuget

I just created a NuGet package for one of my open source projects and it includes a Windows Phone 7 binary. I just tested it and instead of adding the Windows Phone 7-specific library, it added the Silverlight library.

My question is, how can I set up my folder architecture such that the NuGet package manager recognizes my WP7-specific binaries and installs those instead of the Silverlight binaries?

[I followed the instructions listed here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Package) for targeting multiple frameworks in NuGet packages.

Here's what my folder tree currently looks like:

```
\lib
    \.NetFramework 4.0
        \MyAssembly.dll
    \Silverlight 4.0
        \MyAssembly.Silverlight.dll
    \Windows Phone 7
        \MyAssembly.Mobile.dll
```

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't support wp7 natively yet since there is no profile support (the profile part of the framework name isn't supported in folders). See this issue for more details http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/219.

FWIW: Windows phone 7 is Silverlight 4, Profile=Windows Phone.

For now you'll have to create another package for wp7.

Comment: Thanks - not the answer I was hoping for, but at least there's a work-around!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this has been fixed with the [latest version](http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases/view/55760) (1.1) of nuget. You can verify this with the following test (taken straight from the Nuget unit tests):

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParseFrameworkNameWithWPProfileGetNormalizedToWindowsPhone() {
    // Act
    var frameworkName = VersionUtility.ParseFrameworkName("sl4-wp");

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual("Silverlight", frameworkName.Identifier);
    Assert.AreEqual(new Version("4.0"), frameworkName.Version);
    Assert.AreEqual("WindowsPhone", frameworkName.Profile);
}
```